# Firebase function timeout when calling external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call an external API in Firebase Functions but i always get a timeout.
What can be the issue causing this?

Here is my code

```
exports.getCountryData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

const https = require('https');
const options = {
  hostname: "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3",
  path: '/fixtures?next=5',
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "my-api-key"
  }
};
  var req = https.get(options, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Api fetched successfully");

        console.log(result);
   
        response.send({ fulfillmentText: result});
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => { console.log("Error: " + err.message); });
});
```

Comment: loading ```api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3``` in a new browser tab takes forever. that's the issue

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I changed the host from api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3 to v3.football.api-sports.io and it's now working fine

Comment: Hi @tate_xy Please post the answer so that community members visiting the question, should know what solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out using their Rapid Api url (**api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3**) was was resulting in a timeout. Using a direct Api url (**v3.football.api-sports.io**) with their domain name in it did the trick for me.

**Here is my working code.**

```
exports.getCountryData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

const https = require('https');
const options = {
  hostname: "v3.football.api-sports.io",
  path: '/fixtures?next=5',
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    "x-apisports-key": "my-api-key"
  }
};
  var req = https.get(options, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Api fetched successfully");

        console.log(result);
   
        response.send({ fulfillmentText: result});
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => { console.log("Error: " + err.message); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An event-driven function may fail to successfully complete due to errors thrown in the function code itself. Some of the reasons this might happen are as follows:

- The function contains a bug and the runtime throws an exception.
- The function cannot reach a service endpoint, or times out while
  trying to reach the endpoint.
- The function intentionally throws an exception (for example, when a
  parameter fails validation).
- When functions written in Node.js return a rejected promise or pass a
  non-null value to a callback.

In any of the above cases, the function stops executing by default and the event is discarded. If you want to retry the function when an error occurs, you can change the default retry policy by [setting the "retry on failure"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries) property. This causes the event to be retried repeatedly for up to multiple days until the function successfully completes.

In this question, the service endpointi `‘api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3’` itself took so much time to load ( not reachable ), that was the issue. Changing the API endpoint to `v3.football.api-sports.io` and then calling the external API in Firebase Functions solved the issue for our user @tate_xy